# How to stop loading multiple copies of jquery

Tags: php, jquery, headers

My wordpress header.php and function.php is given below.please help me to modify my php code to stop problems due to loading jquery multiple times. My plugins and themes are loading jquery multiple times.

My files
[Header.php](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KTqj6LJT) 
[Function.php](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=e6eiHmWx)

---

All experts are telling that i need to include enqueue script !!! I read different documents related to it.

I'm new to coding , i dont know where to add this enqueue script, what type of code I need to add?

Comment: Vijitha, please do not use services like pastebin or similars. In case they go down, nobody will understand your problem. Please file an [edit] and put the code where it belongs: In your question.

Answer (score 3):

You should remove these lines from your header.php

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/javascripts/tabber.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/javascripts/superfish.js"></script>
```

And instead add the following function in your functions php...
right at the top.

**wp_enqueue_script**

```
function sg_theme_js(){

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tabberjs', get_template_directory_uri().'/javascripts/tabber.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'superfishjs', get_template_directory_uri().'/javascripts/superfish.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sg_theme_js' );
```

**Explenation:**
Since many plugins use jQuery (and other js files) they need to know (and wordpress too) that you already loaded jQuery... but, they cannot check it after the page has loaded meaning by checking your header becouse that is too late!

That is why we should enqueue scripts and those allow plugins to depened on them.

**Now... a small comment.**
if you wish to manage your theme meaning deal with code you need to learn this stuff ;) - take a moment to read about wp_enqueue_script.

Here is additional information about: [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to never add script tags directly to template files. This is exactly why the WordPress script [registration](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [enqueue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) system exists.

Comment: I already read the document you suggested, but it is difficult to understand for me.can you tell me the code i needed to edit in above php files.

Comment: can you tell me where to place enqueue code in my php file?

Comment: it should go in your theme's [`functions.php` file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained).

Comment: so you are telling that I should remain my header.php as it is?

Comment: no, you need to remove the script tags and enqueue those scripts instead.

Comment: can you give me the enqueue code? thanks

Comment: I'm not expert in coding, so I'm asking it.sorry if it is against the website policy. ...thanks